# Update Database field on Form Submission - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

What This does is gets the data from the db where 'approve' field's value is '0'. Displays the form. Now what we want to do here is to UPDATE the value of the 'approve' field to '1' on the click of the "Approve" Button. I think there is some issue with the IF condition or something, not sure. No issue in connecting to the db. Or do i need to close the db connection or commit or something for update to take place, not sure. Thanks for the help.

```
require("dbconn.php");
// get the form data and store it in the database
// show database data
$query="SELECT * FROM page where approve=0";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if ($result)
{
    print "<b>Approval pending for below listings.</b><br><br>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<form name="submit_form" action="" method="post">';

        $page_url = $row['page_url'];
        $contact_number = $row['contact_number'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $business_name = $row['business_name'];

        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"business_link\" value=\"$page_url\" readonly><br/>";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"contact_number\" value=\"$contact_number\" readonly><br/>";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"description\" value=\"$description\" readonly><br/>";
        echo "enter code here`<input type=\"text\" name=\"category\" value=\"$category\" readonly><br/>";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"address\" value=\"$address\" readonly><br/>";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"business_name\" value=\"$business_name\" readonly><br/>";
        echo "<input type=\"Submit\" Value=\"Approve\" name=\"submit\"/>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<hr><br>";
        if($_POST['submit_form'] == "submit")
        {
                mysql_query("UPDATE page SET approve='1' WHERE business_name='$business_name' AND contact_number='$contact_number' AND page_url='$page_url' AND description='$description' AND address='$address' AND category='$category'");
                echo "Thank you!";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    print mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's getting to the query? Does it echo out the 'Thank you'? If so, try just echoing out the query itself and running it manually in phpMyAdmin or SQL workbench. That will help you to identify errors with the query.

Comment: From that form, it looks like you're not submitting anything with a name of `submit_form`. That's the name of your form, but that's not going to come in as a post var.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for "submit_form", but you should be checking for "submit" from your Submit button.

Comment: Should add that `submit` has a value of "Approve", not "submit".

Answer (score 1):

Change:-

```
if($_POST['submit_form'] == "submit")
```

to following:-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Approve")
```

Also, you should put the above code after "require("dbconn.php");", like following:-

```
require("dbconn.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Approve"){
   // update query here
   // show notification
   // you can show form too
}else{
   // display the form
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One issue here is that suppose there are two forms, so two Approve button. When I click on the first button, multiple rows gets updated which i don't want. I want one at a time. 
I am trying to figure out a solution here by using some flag or something like that. If any body can help on this as well then it would be of great help.
Refer Above Form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the php code `isset($_POST['submit'])` and check whether button is submitting or not.Also remove the `<input type="Submit"......>` to `<input type="submit"......>`.Echo the SQL queries and check whether all values are coming in the query.